# Share and NTFS Permissions Issue

Tags: windows-7, ntfs, windows-server-2008-r2, shared-folders

I am facing a domain level issue, the problem description is;

1. I try to create a folder and Named "Folder 1" and share it with every one with "Read" permissions only.
2. I created another folder inside "Folder 1" named "Child".
3. I set the security permission of the folder for "User 1" and "Domain Administrator" as Full.

The problem that I am facing is the users for which i have set permissions full are not able to create/modify and files in the "Folder 1". This is happening across the domain. 
I have tried practising the same on the File Server as well as on the desktop PCs but the same issue is coming up.

How is this issue resolved?

Answer (score 1):

Setting a folder to be shared as Read only means nobody can write to it over the network irrespective of the security permissions of the folders inside.

What you want is to set the sharing permissions as Read/Write - the security permissions on the folders themselves then take effect to decide who can do what.

Comment: putting the parent folder as read/write for everyone ?
This will also enable all users to modify the contents in the child folders. right?

Comment: In the sharing dialog, yes. Then use the NTFS permissions instead to restrict it to read only as these will still apply (the sharing permissions do not override the NTFS ones)

Comment: That was the perfect resolution to my problem.
Thank You

Comment: @AbdulWajid If you feel the question has been answered, please indicate so by clicking the green check mark outline in the left column, next to the voting arrows, corresponding to the answer that you found most useful. Accepting and voting are the customary ways of saying thanks on Stack Exchange sites, including SuperUser.